# I want to repeat the same form x times in a loop and display it with twig

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I want to repeat the form in a loop and display it with twig 
in the controller:

```
<?php

foreach ($folder as $file) {
  $form [] = $this->get('form.factory')->create(UploadFileType::class, $file);
}

return $this->render('Admin/view-folder.html.twig', array(
  'form' => $form->createView()
));

//the formtype

class UploadFileType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('file', FileType::class)
      ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: RTFM?: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html Probably you must call form builder once for all instances

Comment: Are you sure you want 5 individual forms or do you want one form capable of uploading 5 files at a time?

Comment: no i want the same forms repeated many times

Comment: @zarathoustra Well okay.  Obviously $form->createView() is not going to work well when $form is an array.  I would start by renaming $form to $forms just to help keep track of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "CollectionType" field as explained in the [Symfony documentation.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)